# How can I get bytes to display their character representations from different codepages?

Tags: c#, unicode

I've been trying to create a consistent method to take the bytes of characters and display the bytes representation in alternative text codepages. For example, hex D1 in Windows 1251, KOI-8U, etc. The idea is to take text that appears scrambled, because it is being interpreted and displayed in the wrong character set and transform it to the correct display. Below is a shortened portion of the code I've used. I've gotten it to work on ideone, but can't get it to work as an add-type in powershell or compiling with csc. I just get question marks or incorrect characters.

The output of the below code from ideone, which is the correct transformation, is:

D1-00-C1-00

СБ

windows-1251

When compiled with PowerShell or csc it is (incorrect):

D1-00-C1-00

?A

windows-1251

Is there a way to make this work in the Windows environment?

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "ÑÁ"
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        char[] ca = enc.GetChars(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine(ca);
        Console.WriteLine(enc.HeaderName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE/SOLUTION

As roeland notes, there's quite a bit of guess work involved with this. The problem as a C# solution is also two parts on Windows. It appears that the display default encoding for the console doesn't change with the encoding object automatically (it seems to with Mac and the Mono Framework). The console display has to be set manually with SetConsoleCP and SetConsoleOutputCP. I also had to create multiple encodings and use an inner loop to get the proper intersection of codepages. The link below pointed towards the display issue's resolution.

UTF-8 output from PowerShell

Example below is focused on scenario where Russian is the suspected language.

CODE

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Language
{
   public class Test
   {
      //Imports dll to set console display
       [DllImport("kernel32.dll"]
       public static extern bool SetConsoleCP(int codepage);
       [DllImport("kernel32.dll"]
       public static extern bool SetConsoleOutputCP(int codepage);
   public static void Main()
    {
       string s = "ÑÁÅ";
       byte[] bytes = new byte[s.Length * sizeof(char)];
       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(s.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0,  bytes.Length);
       Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
     //produce possible combinations
       foreach (Encoding encw in Russian.GetCps())
       {
          bool cp = SetConsoleOutputCP(encw.CodePage);
          bool cp2 = SetConsoleCP(encw.CodePage);
          foreach (Encoding enc in Russian.GetCps())
          {
              char[] ca = enc.GetChars(bytes);
              Console.WriteLine(ca);
           }
         }
       }
     }
public class Russian
{
    public static Encoding[] GetCps()
    {
     // get applicable Cyrillic pages
     Encoding[] = russian = new Encoding[8];
     russian[0] = Encoding.GetEncoding(855);  
     russian[1] = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);     
     russian[2] = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251); 
     russian[3] = Encoding.GetEncoding(10007); 
     russian[4] = Encoding.GetEncoding(20866); 
     russian[5] = Encoding.GetEncoding(21866); 
     russian[6] = Encoding.GetEncoding(20880); 
     russian[7] = Encoding.GetEncoding(28595);
     return russian;
    } 
 }
}
```

The output is lengthy, but gives a string with the correct output as one member of a list.

I made a shorter version in PowerShell, which appears to change the display codepage automatically and requires less iterations:

```
function Get-Language ([string]$source) {

$encodings = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(855),[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(866),[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1251),[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(10007),[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(20866),[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(21866),[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(20880),[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28595)

$C = ""
$bytes = gc $source -encoding byte
for ($i=0; $i -le $encodings.Length - 1; $i++) {
$bytes | %{$C = $C + $encodings[$i].GetChars($_)}
Write-Host $C
$C = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the best way to solve this *problem* is to avoid it—make sure that when you have bytes, you always know which character set was used to encode these bytes.

To answer the question: **you can't**. There is no consistent method to make this work anywhere. This will always involve guesswork.

What you see is a string which was encoded to bytes with some encoding, and then decoded using a *different* encoding. Here is how you fix these strings:

1. figure out (or *guess*) what encoding was originally used to encode the string to bytes.
2. figure out (or *guess*) what encoding was used when displaying the string,
3. reverse the operations: encode the mojibake using the encoding from step (2) and encode the bytes with the encoding from step (1)

If you already have *bytes*, you only do step (1) and use that decoding to decode the bytes to a string.

A program doing that would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // our corrupted string
        string str = "ÑÁ"

        // encoding from step (2)
        Encoding enc1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        byte[] bytes = enc1.GetBytes(str);

        // encoding from step (1)
        Encoding enc2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        string originalStr = enc.GetString(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(originalStr);
    }
}
```